# Mysql getting all the children

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hierarchical-data

Say I have a data base with classes and requirements that looks like this for example:

```
+--------+------+
| course |prereq|
+--------+------+
| 1      |  null|
| 2      |  null|
| 3      |    1 |
| 3      |    2 |
| 4      |    3 |
| 5      |    4 |
+--------+------+
```

And I want to find all the prereqs for course 4.  So my answer would be 3,2,1.
Also this is just an example I want to be able to use this for a table of any size.

How would I go about doing this in mysql?

Comment: And for 5, would it be 4, 3, 2, 1 ?

Comment: Please update the question with your query? what efforts have u made

Comment: Yes, for 5 it would be 4,3,2,1

Comment: are the courses always numerically and in the proper order starting at 1? or was your example overly simple?

Comment: I fully addressed how to do this with Stored Procedures in the DBA StackExchange : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is about [hierarchical joins in mysql](https://www.google.com/search?q=hierarchical%20joins%20in%20mysql&oq=hierarchical%20joins%20in%20mysql&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.159j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

With a sort of logic and a stored function will do the trick for you.

[This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7161/4238) thread surely will lead you.

Have a try.

Comment: +1 I love the link to a google search! Makes the OP do some research, but sometimes knowing what to search for is the tricky part